# Username is not showing but user id is showing in html template in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset, django-annotate, django-aggregation

Below is my Model :

```
class Problem_Solved(models.Model):
    user_ref = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contest_ref = models.ForeignKey(Contest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    problem_ref = models.ForeignKey(Problem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points_get = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    time_submitted = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user_ref", "problem_ref"))
        

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_ref.username + " solved " + self.problem_ref.problem_name + " and got " + str(self.points_get) + " marks "
```

Below is my view function :

```
def pointtable(request, contest_id):
    context = {}
    contest_obj=Contest.objects.get(pk=contest_id)
    points_list = Problem_Solved.objects.filter(contest_ref = 
      contest_obj).values('user_ref').annotate(user_sum = Sum('points_get')).order_by('-user_sum')
    print(points_list)
    context['points_list'] = points_list
    return render(request,'leaderboard.html', context)
```

Now below is my html code :

```
{% for pt in points_list %}
            <div class="container-sm w-75  tb-bg-color">
                <div class="row mb-3 ">
                    <div class="col-1 themed-grid-col col-border">{{forloop.counter}}</div>
                    <div class="col-6 themed-grid-col col-border">{{pt.user_ref.username}}</div>
                    <div class="col-2 themed-grid-col col-border">{{pt.user_sum}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Below is output :

[Username is not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnwdr.png)

As clearly seen in image that username is not showing but if I write pt.user_ref in my html code then it will print user_id as shown below :

[User id is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbwJt.png)

Now I want username but not user id what should i do as I am stuck with this from 2 days. Help me if u can.

Comment: show your **User** models

Comment: You have used `values` to perform a group by. This returns a dictionary of values with the foreign keys represented by their ids (which is why the username doesn't show up).

Comment: I haven't created User model. I have used default user model provided by Djnago

Comment: Okay @AbdulAzizBarkat but if I remove values then it is not doing sum of user's points_get. Is there any other way I can show username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the points tally of each user annotate on the `User` model instead, this way you will get a QuerySet of `User` objects so you can simply get the username:

```py
def pointtable(request, contest_id):
    context = {}
    contest_obj=Contest.objects.get(pk=contest_id)
    contest_users = User.objects.filter(
        problem_solved__contest_ref = contest_obj
    ).annotate(
        point_sum=Sum('problem_solved__points_get')
    ).order_by('-point_sum')
    context['contest_users'] = contest_users
    return render(request,'leaderboard.html', context)
```

Now your html would be:

```
{% for contest_user in contest_users %}
    <div class="container-sm w-75  tb-bg-color">
        <div class="row mb-3 ">
            <div class="col-1 themed-grid-col col-border">{{forloop.counter}}</div>
            <div class="col-6 themed-grid-col col-border">{{contest_user.username}}</div>
            <div class="col-2 themed-grid-col col-border">{{contest_user.point_sum}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

> **Note**: Class names should not have underscores in them. So `ProblemSolved` instead of `Problem_Solved`